# How to correctly delete all the packages in the pacman cache and why I shouldn't?

Tags: manjaro, pacman

I struggle from insufficient space on my SSD all the time. Every time a major upgrade including a serious number of packages arrives I have to seek what can I delete/move to free up some space so the upgrade could succeed. `pacman -Sc` deletes old packages from the pacman cache but seemingly leaves non-old packages in place. My `\var\cache\pacman` is 5.1 GiB now and this is a significant number for me.  Are these files needed for anything useful but to install the apps? Given the apps are already installed and work just fine can I delete the packages? If it's Ok to delete them, what is the correct way I should use instead of just deleting the files manually?

Comment: Try `pacman -Scc`

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 thanks. Done the job. Now the update is in progress.. Let's see if it completes Ok...

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 `pacman -Scc` seems to be the right answer. Please post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's fine to delete all the packages, but there is several advantages if we keep it, such as :

1. It allows to downgrade a package without the need to retrieve the previous version through other means, such as the Arch Linux Archive.
2. A package that has been uninstalled can easily be reinstalled directly from the cache folder, not requiring a new download from the repository.

Ref : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/pacman#Cleaning_the_package_cache